# qualifier errors

Tags: c++, qt

I keep getting this `passing 'const QString' as 'this' argument of 'QString& QString::operator=(const QString&)' discards qualifiers` error and I don't know why... I already somewhat isolated this piece to make free of external causes but still persists.

```
QVector< QPair<QString, QString> > some;
some.at(0).first = QString("HA");
```

Ignore the fact that I'm working with an empty vector, unless it's the source of the problem. :( It should only create a runtime error instead of a compile-time error, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**const** T & QVector::at ( int i ) const

You cannot assign value to const reference.

use

```
some[0]
```

in order to get a non-const reference